# Navigate Parent Site from Embedded App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am developing an internal google site and have been utilizing embedded app scripts to facilitate more complex functions on the site.  I've run into a road block however in that I want to provide the ability to edit a record, utilizing another page that's already been developed, but navigating to it from the web app using a button.  When clicking the button, it would navigate the iframe parent (the site) to the URL I desire.  Currently, I get a javascript error indicating that

```
> "VM804:5 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame
> with URL
> 'https://n-z2vljuo5gowvr7ouc7uiijx7cxg3lrswlus2nqq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'
> from frame with URL
> 'https://n-z2vljuo5gowvr7ouc7uiijx7cxg3lrswlus2nqq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'.
> The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore
> disallowed from navigating its ancestors."
```

Has anyone else had similar issues and been able to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `allow-top-navigation` which re-enables changing parent frame `window.location`.

Check [Guidelines and Limitations of the HTML Code and Embed a Site Elements](https://support.wix.com/en/article/guidelines-and-limitations-of-the-html-code-and-embed-a-site-elements) and [W3C specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#sandboxed-document.domain-browsing-context-flag) to learn more.